# Lector de texto en HTML con JavaScript que vaya resaltando el texto que se lee

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy desarrollando una página web en HTML con JavaScript que permite leer el texto seleccionado por el usuario utilizando el evento de selección del mouse. Sin embargo, estoy enfrentando un problema con el resaltado de las palabras. El resaltado marca palabras que ya se han leído previamente, lo cual no es deseado en mi aplicación.

La funcionalidad que busco implementar es similar a un lector de texto a voz, donde el texto seleccionado se lee en voz alta y se resalta a medida que se avanza en la lectura. Pero necesito encontrar una forma de evitar que las palabras ya leídas se vuelvan a resaltar, específicamente evitando el resaltado de palabras a la izquierda del punto actual de lectura.

Mi objetivo final es utilizar esta funcionalidad en una plataforma educativa para niños con capacidades diferentes, donde puedan seleccionar un texto y escucharlo mientras se resalta de manera dinámica.

Me gustaría recibir sugerencias y recomendaciones sobre cómo abordar este problema. ¿Hay alguna técnica o librería específica que pueda utilizar para lograr el resaltado de texto sin marcar palabras previamente leídas hacia la izquierda?

Agradecería mucho cualquier orientación o ayuda que puedan brindarme. ¡Gracias de antemano!

```js
// A simple IIFE function. 
(function () {
  "use strict";

  if (typeof speechSynthesis === 'undefined')
    return;

  var voiceSelect = document.getElementById("voiceSelect");
  var voices = [];
  var textElements = document.querySelectorAll('p');

  function populateVoiceList() {
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();

    for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.textContent = voices[i].name + ' (' + voices[i].lang + ')';
      option.textContent += voices[i].default ? ' -- DEFAULT' : '';
      option.setAttribute('data-lang', voices[i].lang);
      option.setAttribute('data-name', voices[i].name);
      document.getElementById("voiceSelect").appendChild(option);
    }
  }

  function speakText(text) {
    var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
    var selectedOption = voiceSelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-name');

    for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
      if (voices[i].name === selectedOption) {
        utterThis.voice = voices[i];
      }
    }

    utterThis.addEventListener('start', function () {
      textElements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.remove('highlighted');
      });
    });

    utterThis.addEventListener('boundary', function (event) {
      var start = event.charIndex;
      var end = event.charIndex + event.charLength;

      textElements.forEach(function (element) {
        var text = element.textContent;
        if (start >= 0 && end <= text.length) {
          var highlightedText = text.substring(start, end);
          var regex = new RegExp(highlightedText, 'gi');
          element.innerHTML = text.replace(regex, '<span class="highlighted">' + highlightedText + '</span>');
        }
      });
    });

    speechSynthesis.speak(utterThis);
  }

  function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
  }

  document.onmouseup = function (e) {
    var selectedText = getSelectionText();
    if (selectedText.length > 0) {
      speakText(selectedText);
    }
  };

  function start() {
    populateVoiceList();
    if (speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined)
      speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = populateVoiceList;

    voiceSelect.onchange = function () {
      var selectedText = getSelectionText();
      if (selectedText.length > 0) {
        speakText(selectedText);
      }
    };

    setTimeout(function () {
      var defaultOption = voiceSelect.querySelector('[data-default="true"]');
      if (defaultOption) {
        defaultOption.selected = true;
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        if (selectedText.length > 0) {
          speakText(selectedText);
        }
      }
    }, 75);
  }

  start();
})();
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <hr/>
  <select id="voiceSelect"></select>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <p>Testing... Testing... One Two Three... Testing</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>hola hola, adiós hola.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```